# Bug with equals operator and NSObjects in Swift 2.0?

Tags: equality, nsobject, swift2

Ok, something strange is happening when writing your own equals operator for NSObject subclasses in Swift 2.0 like this:

```
func ==(lhs: MyObject, rhs: MyObject) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
}
```

For a class that looks like this:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    let identifier: String
    init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }
}
```

This used to work just fine in Swift 1.2 and below. It still kind of works:

```
let myObject1 = MyObject(identifier: "A")
let myObject2 = MyObject(identifier: "A")
let result = (myObject1 == myObject2)
// result is true
```

So far so good, but what if both of the variables were optionals?

```
let myObject1: MyObject? = MyObject(identifier: "A")
let myObject2: MyObject? = MyObject(identifier: "A")
let result = (myObject1 == myObject2)
// result is false, equals operator was never even called
```

And one other thing that no longer works:

```
let myObject1 = MyObject(identifier: "A")
let myObject2 = MyObject(identifier: "A")
let result = (myObject1 == myObject2)
// result is true
let result = (myObject1 != myObject2)
// result is true, equals operator was never even called
```

So apparently, != no longer calls the == operator and negates it. It seems to just compare the instances instead when using !=

All of this only happens when your class is a subclass of NSObject (directly or indirectly). When it's not, everything works just like you would expect.

Can anyone tell me if this is a new 'feature' in Swift 2.0 or just a nasty bug?

Comment: Did you mean to write `==`, instead of `=`, in your `==` function? Could be the cause of the strange behaviour, I haven't tested this though.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the cause (see my answer below) but you're right it should be `==`

Comment: Sorry, typo. But that indeed wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know whether this is considered a feature or not (I don't think so). This problem occurs if any class subclasses a class which conforms to `Equatable`(like `NSObject`; it compares actual instances). So if you only "override" the `==` operator of the subclass all other operators like:

```
func !=<T : Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool
```

where `T` is constrained to be `Equatable` Swift uses the `==` operator of the baseclass. As (time-consuming) workaround you can overload all the equality operators you have to use like so:

```
func !=(lhs: MyObject, rhs: MyObject) -> Bool { ... }
func ==(lhs: MyObject?, rhs: MyObject?) -> Bool { ... }
func ==(lhs: [MyObject], rhs: [MyObject]) -> Bool { ... }
```

**Edit: The Reason**

The reason for this behavior is that if a subclass conforms to `Equatable` the `Self` of the self requirement is determined to be this class. So every time the `==` is called with a (generic) type that conforms to `Equatable` it only calls the operator of the initial conforming class.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: This is still present in the Xcode 7 GM. Did you ever find out if it's an intentional change?

Comment: @Bill I found out that this behavior even exists in Swift 1.2 and I edited my answer (reason of this behavior).

Answer (score 10):

I think this behavior should be considered a bug (still present as of Xcode 7 beta 6), but there's a hopefully temporary workaround: override NSObject's `-isEqual` instead of implementing Swift's `==` operator.

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    let identifier: String
    init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }
    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        guard let rhs = object as? MyObject else {
            return false
        }
        let lhs = self

        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

I found another reference to the problem, with more code examples, here: http://mgrebenets.github.io/swift/2015/06/21/equatable-nsobject-with-swift-2/

Answer (score 0):

[kylealanhale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342485/1346426) does not work with `NSManagedObject` (explained [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6337)), so I created a new protocol `NSObjectSubclassEquatable` that you can use for comparing `NSobject` subclasses.

```
infix operator =~= {}

public protocol NSObjectSubclassEquatable {

  static func compare(lhs: Self,_ rhs: Self) -> Bool
}


public func =~=<T : NSObjectSubclassEquatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {

  return T.compare(lhs, rhs)
}

func =~=<Element : NSObjectSubclassEquatable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> Bool {
  for (lhsElement,rhsElement) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
    if !(lhsElement =~= rhsElement) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Example:

```
class Point: NSObject {

  var x: Int
  var y: Int

  init(_ x: Int,_ y: Int) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  }
}

extension Point: NSObjectSubclassEquatable {

  static func compare(lhs: Point,_ rhs: Point) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
  }
}

Point(1,2) =~= Point(1,2) // Prints true
[Point(1,2)] =~= [Point(1,2)] // Prints true
```