# XCTAssertEqual not working for Equatable types in Swift

Tags: swift, xctest

Given the following Swift class:

```
class TestObject: NSObject {
    let a: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
        super.init()
    }
}

func ==(lhs: TestObject, rhs: TestObject) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a
}
```

and a test case for it:

```
func testExample() {
    let a = TestObject(a: 4)
    let b = TestObject(a: 4)

    XCTAssertEqual(a, b) // fails

    let isEqual = a == b
    XCTAssert(isEqual) // passes       
}
```

the two assert's return different values, but they should both pass.

I tried writing a custom assert function:

```
func BAAssertEquatable<A: Equatable>(x1: A, _ x2: A, _ message: String, file: String = __FILE__, line: UInt = __LINE__) {
    let operandsEqual = (x1 == x2)
    XCTAssert(operandsEqual, message, file: file, line: line)
}
```

but this also fails:

```
BAAssertEquatable(a, b, "custom assert") // fails
```

What's going on here?

Comment: +1 for the very good analysis. Unfortunately I can only guess the issue and recommend further analysis. For me it looks like swift somewhere looses the information that your 'TestObject' implements the Equatable Protocol. Could you add a 'print' to your Operator func? I expect that it is not called in the cases in question. Additionally I'd expect an 'override' somehow in front of 'func =='. Sorry that I cannot help better at the moment.

Comment: @jboi You're right - the == operator is only being called once (in the direct call in testExample), but it should be called three times. I can't use the override keyword at the top level (it's a syntax error).

Comment: I think this is related to the bug/issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099379/bug-with-equals-operator-and-nsobjects-in-swift-2-0

Comment: Just because you have a `==` function does not mean `TestObject` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol. You must explicitly declare conformance just like you would with any other protocol.

Comment: @PeterSchorn Of course, but in the example, my class inherits from `NSObject`, which conforms to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 9):

`XCTAssertEqual` calls `isEqual` instead of `==`, e.g. this will make your test pass:

```
class TestObject: NSObject {

    // ...
    
    override public func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let other = object as? TestObject else { return false }
        return self == other
    }
    
}
```