# How exactly does == work with Set() - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, set

I'm running this code

```
if(left.comboOptions.count != right.comboOptions.count) {
    for index in 0...left.comboOptions.count-1  {
        print(left.comboOptions[index].selectedComboOptionDishes == right.comboOptions[index].selectedComboOptionDishes)
        print(left.comboOptions[index].selectedComboOptionDishes)
        print("vs")
        print(right.comboOptions[index].selectedComboOptionDishes)
        print()
    }
}
```

And the output I got was

```
Comparing comboOptionDish
1x Black Beans Wrap(277) vs 1x Black Beans Wrap(277)
Both are equal

true
[1x Black Beans Wrap(277)]
vs
[1x Black Beans Wrap(277)]

false
[1x Fresh Lemon Juice(292)]
vs
[1x Fresh Lemon Juice(292)]

true
[]
vs
[]
```

> **Why is == on Set() returning `false` on index 1 (second one here)?? and Why is `==` block not executed for `Fresh Lemon Juice`???**
>   What am I doing wrong? Or the way == operates on Set() differs specifically?

and my ComboOptionDish class is

```
class ComboOptionDish: Equatable, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {

    var id: Int!
    var quantity: Int = 0
    var dish: Dish! /*Contains name, id and price and nothing else*/
    var description: String {
        return String(quantity) + "x " + dish.name + "(" + String(id) + ")"
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.id * self.quantity
    }
}

func == (left: ComboOptionDish, right: ComboOptionDish) -> Bool {
    print("Comparing comboOptionDish")
    print(String(left) + " vs " + String(right))
    if left.id != right.id { print("IDs not equal\n"); return false }
    if left.quantity != right.quantity { print("Quantity not equal\n"); return false }
    print("Both are equal")
    print()
    return true
}
```

My ComboOption class is

```
class ComboOption: Mappable, Equatable {

    var id: Int!
    var name: String!
    var selectedComboOptionDishes: Set<ComboOptionDish> = Set()
    var comboOptionDishes: ComboOptionDish = []

}
```

EDIT: How I fill data?

- I fill in data using JSON using ObjectMapper.
- I have many `ComboOption`s each containing many `ComboOptionDish`es.
- Then I make user choose `ComboOptionDish`es, which I add to `selectedComboOptionDishes` which is a `Set()` of `ComboOptionDish`es inside the corresponding `ComboOption`
- And then I now need to compare if two `ComboOption`s are equal, so I need to override `==` for `ComboOption`

Comment: Can you add the code for creating `left.comboOptions` and `right.comboOptions`.

Comment: I've added an Edit, but posting all that would be toooooooo much code i think

Comment: Why is there no output of "Both are equal" for the "Fresh Lemon Juice"? Apart from that I am confused as you are why this code does not behave as expected.

Comment: Exactly, it is not going inside `==` for `Fresh lemon juice`! I am not able to figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your problem but I believe it's a bug with the equality overload. There's a similar topic about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099379/bug-with-equals-operator-and-nsobjects-in-swift-2-0).

The workaround is to have `ComboOptionDish` subclass `NSObject` and use `isEqual` .

```
class ComboOptionDish: NSObject {
    override var description: String {
        //...
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        //...
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? ComboOptionDish {
            return self.id == other.id && self.quantity == other.quantity
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```